I used FedEx return shipping label for my Canada visiting visa (to New York center)
I used a FedEx return shipping label for my passport for a Canada visit visa (shipped with FedEx to New York center). Now I see they don’t accept return labels from FedEx. What do I do?

What did the VAC say when you asked them?
